# ASP.Net Core WebApi projects in VS 2022: 404 when renaming controller

Tags: asp.net, angular

I rarely dive into web development and was using the following link to build a small project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022

Using this project I've gone to rename the controller and now when loading the page the request returns a 404. If I name it back the page loads as expected (in the three components below by renaming Products to WeatherForecast). The 3 places I re-named are below. This is still using dummy data as I learn angular.

What am I missing by doing a simple rename here?

product.component.ts:

```
 export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
 public forecasts?: Products[];

 constructor(http: HttpClient) {
 http.get<Products[]>('/products').subscribe(result => {
  this.forecasts = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
}
```

proxy.conf.js:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/products",
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7050",
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Products controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
     [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<ProductsController> _logger;

        public ProductsController(ILogger<ProductsController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetProducts")]
        public IEnumerable<Products> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new Products
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

404:[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to your HttpErrorResponse, you are not sending request to .NET API, but to `localhost:4200` which I believe is your Angular application.

Try sending request like this:

```
http.get<Products[]>('https://localhost:7050/products').subscribe...
```

If that works, your proxy configuration is messing with the request. Be sure to get the port right and to start Angular application after .NET application has started. You can check your ports in `launchSettings.json`, be careful because http and https use different ports. Use `http` if your certificates are not configured.

Don't forget to include `proxy.conf.json` in `angular.json` under `"serve"` like this:

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
```

Comment: I'm working on testing this. I do believe the call is going to the .NET  API. For reference as well if in the snippets I provided I replace 'products' with 'weatherforecast' the application pulls in the data. Is it possible that route is cached somewhere in the angular app? Thank you for taking the time to help!!

Comment: That happens because controller name is located in a few places in your .NET application so it is not that convenient to rename it. Your quick solution could be using [Route("products")]. Try using this routing and let me know if it works. Then you could rename all occasions of weatherforecast, but it would be easier to just create new controller with desired name.

Answer (score 1):

To extend @Ocram's answer - which is absolutely correct and relevant -, I also found that if you have a **context: []** list in your **PROXY_CONFIG** definition in the **proxy.conf.js** file *(the list of paths/controllers you want to redirect to the backend port)*, then you need to ensure that this list contains all the controller names you need.

It is because when you rename a controller, you also need to inform the client proxy config about the change.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        ///-----------------
        context: [  
            "/weatherforecast",
            "/test",
            "/mynewapi",
        ],
        ///-----------------
        changeOrigin: true,
        target: target,
        secure: false,
        headers: {
            Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
        }
    }
]
```